# Issue with login using email and password in PHP

Tags: php, database, authentication

```
<?php
$msg = "";
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'sconnect');
    $email = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $semail=$email;
    $password = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $sql = $con->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND 
    password='$password';");

    if ($email == "" || $password == "")
        $msg = "Please check your inputs!";
    else if ($sql) 
    {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $semail;
        header('Location:../home.php');
    }
    else 
    {
        $msg = "Please check your inputs!";
    }
}
?>
```

With this code I am able to login with any input in the password field. Please solve the problem.

Comment: All you test is that the SQL query succeeded, not that there was a row returned. Even if no rows are returned, the query was still run successfully. There a lots of other sides issues with this code too, which I'll leave for others to mention.

Comment: Do not escape your password as it can change it. In fact, you should skip the escaping completely and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). Passwords should also be hashed using the [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) functions, so that they are secure.

Comment: It's nice to be able to look up a password for someone, but it's probably better to hash them properly before storing them in a database. Now anyone who has access to your database has access to plaintext, unhashed passwords of all your users. Also note that the database operations are wide open for SQL Injection: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: `$semail=$email;` WHY

Comment: You use `$email` and `$password` in a query and then AFTERWARDS you check if they are `== ''` Seems a bit late for that check to be honest

Comment: @Loek - "It's nice to be able to look up a password for someone, but it's probably better to hash them properly before storing them in a database."* ... no *probably* about it, you're being far too polite ;) [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) ALL THE PASSWORDS!11!! *\*ahem\**

Comment: @CD001 I know, but something about a welcome wagon and all that. Turns out I can be pretty offensive. I blame it on English not being my native language haha

Answer (score -2):

The variable you are checking is $sql and it will be true if you store any value in it. In your case you have SQL query in it. So it will always return true. You should check the num rows returning from the SELECT query in your if statement.

```
$msg = "";
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
    $email = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $semail = $email;
    $password = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $sql = $con->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password';");

    if ($email == "" || $password == "")
        $msg = "Please check your inputs!";
    else if ($sql->num_rows) {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $semail;
        header('Location:../home.php');
    } else {
        $msg = "Please check your inputs!";
    }
}
```

Comment: *Try this -* ... why? Some explanation as to what you've done, and why, would be beneficial to the OP and any future visitors.

Comment: You're first making a SQL query and store the results in `$sql`. Then in the next row, you're trying to make a new query where you're passing the result variable `$sql` as if it was a string containing a SQL query?